# How to render an array of object in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS and am attempting to render an individual object that contains an array of objects.

But I can't get around the `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function` error.

How do I get at the assets array within the parent object (ie data)?

Here's my JS currently:

```
<script type="text/babel">
var ProjectContainer = React.createClass({
    loadProjectsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            this.setState({data: data});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {data: []};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.loadProjectsFromServer();
        setInterval(this.loadProjectsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <Project data={ this.state.data } />
        );
    }
});
var Project = React.createClass({
    rawMarkup: function() {
        var rawMarkup = this.props.data.description_html;
        return { __html: rawMarkup };
    },
    render: function() {
        var assetNodes = this.props.data.map(function (asset) {
            return (
                <Asset key={ asset.pk } art={ asset.art } project={ asset.project } description={ asset.description } />
            );
        });
        return (
            <div>
                { this.props.data.assets }
                <header>
                    <h2 className="lead_head">{ this.props.data.client_name }</h2>
                </header>
                <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ this.rawMarkup() } />
                <ul className="project_asset_list">
                    { assetNodes }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
var Asset = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <li className="asset">
                <span className="asset_description">{ this.props.project }{ this.props.description }</span>
                <a href={ this.props.art } data-title={ this.props.project } data-lightbox="roadtrip">
                    <img src={ this.props.art } alt={ this.props.description } />
                </a>
            </li>
        )
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(
    <ProjectContainer url="{% url 'portfolio_project_detail_api' slug=slug %}" pollInterval={2000} />,
    document.getElementById('project_indiv')
);
</script>
```

Here's the JSON I'm working with:

```
{
    "pk": 2,
    "client_name": "Paz Studios",
    "slug": "paz-studios",
    "description": "[Paz Studios](https://www.facebook.com/pazstudios) offers yoga and Pilates for students at all levels. (I'm a devoted beginner, and their instructors do a great job of making me feel like I belong, alongside all the other limber wonders.)\r\n\r\nI worked with them as they prepared for their grand opening in November 2013 to craft a logo that found an intersection of simplicity and nature.\r\n\r\nI've continued working with them to create posters, flyers, and other promotional materials. And they've continued to work with me: I've got their advanced classes on my bucket list.",
    "description_html": "<p><a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/pazstudios\">Paz Studios</a> offers yoga and Pilates for students at all levels. (I&#8217;m a devoted beginner, and their instructors do a great job of making me feel like I belong, alongside all the other limber&nbsp;wonders.)</p>\n<p>I worked with them as they prepared for their grand opening in November 2013 to craft a logo that found an intersection of simplicity and&nbsp;nature.</p>\n<p>I&#8217;ve continued working with them to create posters, flyers, and other promotional materials. And they&#8217;ve continued to work with me: I&#8217;ve got their advanced classes on my bucket&nbsp;list.</p>",
    "lead_art": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/portfolio/projects/portfolio-preview-paz.png",
    "completion_date": "2013-11-01",
    "project_detail": {
        "self": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/work/paz-studios/?format=json"
    },
    "assets": [
        {
            "pk": 3,
            "description": "logo",
            "project": "Paz Studios",
            "art": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/portfolio/assets/portfolio-asset-paz-logo.png"
        },
        {
            "pk": 4,
            "description": "schedule poster (11x17)",
            "project": "Paz Studios",
            "art": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/portfolio/assets/paz-march-flyer_2.png"
        },
        {
            "pk": 5,
            "description": "class flyer (8.5x11)",
            "project": "Paz Studios",
            "art": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/portfolio/assets/paz-vinyasa-class_2.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Only arrays have a `.map` method. If `this.props.data` is an object, you have to access the property that holds the array. *edit:* I guess you want `this.props.data.assets.map(...)`. FYI, the issue has nothing to do with React.

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding as well. And `this.props.data.assets` should return an array, but I can't call `.map` on it.

Comment: Well, again, you currently do `this.props.data.map()`, not `this.props.data.assets.map()`. I don't see where you are trying to call `.map` on `data.assets`.

Comment: Using `this.props.data.assets.map...` give me the same error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: You should probably change `return {data: []};` to `return {data: {assets: []}};` as well.

Comment: When I do that, I get a new error: `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {pk, description, project, art}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Project`.`

Comment: Actually, that got it once I removed an errant `{ this.props.data.assets }` from my div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in your Ajax all you have write the line in success function `this.setState({data: data});`
 it's not going to work, your **loadProjectsFromServer** function should be look like

```
 loadProjectsFromServer: function() {
  var Current=this;
$.ajax({
    url: this.props.url,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        Current.setState({data: data});
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
    }.bind(this)
    });
},
```

when you will write keyword `this` and the scope of this keyword is your ajax call and that function don't have a state so you have to store your component in variable and then use that variable to access the state in your ajax call

Second if you find the data in your component then your data should in form of JSON if your data in form of object then you have to write like

```
 var actualdata=JSON.parse(this.props.data);
 var assetNodes = Object.keys(actualdata).map(function (asset) {
        return (
            <Asset key={ actualdata[asset].pk } art={ actualdata[asset].art } project={ actualdata[asset].project } description={ actualdata[asset].description } />
        );
    });
```